# Extra info in moderncv title

Tags: titles, moderncv

The `\homepage` info is appearing in the title of `moderncv`. The code works fine in writeLatex, but not on MikTeX. The error is

> missing \begin{document}

Please help.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\moderncvcolor{green} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{10}\mdseries\upshape}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\firstname{Parul} % Your first name
\familyname{Gupta} % Your last name

\address{Address Line 1}{Address Line 2}
%\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
%\phone{(000) 111 1112}
%\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{123xyz@gmail.com}

\homepage{http://gmail.com/}{www.gmail.com} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
```

Comment: Is your MikTeX distribution up to date? The template you're using looks old. For example, I believe the most recent version of `moderncv` uses `\name{Parul}{Gupta}` instead of the two separate commands, `\firstname` and `\familyname`.

Comment: I got the template here http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter

Comment: Have updated MikTex but problem didn't get solved. Still getting the error message "missing \begin{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\homepage` only takes one argument. So, you should just write:

```
\homepage{www.gmail.com}
```

You may want to use the template from CTAN, which can be found [here](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex), as it is the most up to date template.

It seems that the [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) that you're opening from the LaTeX Templates website automatically opens all of the associated `.sty` files in either of the online editors (*i.e.*, sharelatex and writelatex), and it seems that *that* version of `moderncv` is version 1.1. The most recent version on CTAN, however, is version 1.5.1.

It seems that at some point (in particular, in version 1.1), `\homepage` actually could take two arguments, which is why this works on writelatex for you (*i.e.*, because opening the `moderncv` template via the LaTeX Templates website automatically opens and uses the version 1.1 `.sty` files). However, this use seems to have been deprecated in (at least) version 1.5.1, which is the version you will have locally on your machine if your TeX distribution is up to date, since it is the most recent version on CTAN.

This change is not documented in the [`moderncv` changelog](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/CHANGELOG), however, so it's not clear in which version that use of `\homepage` was deprecated.

Comment: @Parul No problem. I've added some information about why it was working on writelatex but not locally on your own machine. If you edit the document in both places, you will want to make sure that you're using the most up to date `.sty` files when you edit it on writelatex.com, otherwise you may run into problems when you compile it on writelatex.com.